# Downloaded file has bad mime-type

Tags: php, http-headers, zip, download, mime-types

I have a PHP script that creates a Zip Archive and then passes it to the browser for download.

This can be easily done via HTTP Response Headers

```
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public')
header('Content-Type: application/zip')
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipPath))
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip')
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary')

echo file_get_contents($zipPath);
```

The file is correctly downloaded. I can also open it. However, when I check the downloaded file `mime-type`, it tells me : `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/zip`.

For file mime-type detection, I use the following snippet :

```
$pathToDownloadedFile = 'somewhere-on-disk';
$file = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
var_dump(
    file_exists($pathToDownloadedFile), 
    finfo_file($file, $pathToDownloadedFile)
);
```

which dumps out :

> true
>   application/octet-stream

I googled the problem but with no luck.
Any piece of help would be very appreciated.

Comment: How do you check the downloaded file's mime-type?

Comment: @CodeCaster with `fileinfo` PHP extension

Comment: I mean please edit your question to show the code you use to check the downloaded file's mime-type.

Comment: So the problem is not in your HTTP headers, but in `finfo_file()`. A file on disk doesn't store a mime type, it is inferred from "magic number" (first few bytes in file) and file extension. When you search the web for that you'll find that you need to verify your "magic file" installation. What does `mime_content_type()` tell you about the file?

Comment: @CodeCaster It also returns `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Verify your lib_magic installation.

Comment: @CodeCaster This is a bit confusing :s `finfo_file` or `mime_content_type` on the "original" file (whose path is in $zipPath) gives `application/zip`.

Comment: Your source file has .zip extension. What extension does your downloaded file have?

Comment: @CodeCaster `.zip` too